# jQuery's load() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple script that's supposed to load comments every second but for some reason it doesn't work. Here's code

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#comments").load('url to comments.php');
}), 1000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="comments"></div>
</body>
```

I tried few things like changing "url to comments.php" to just "comments.php" but to no avail. JQuery won't even load simple .txt file. I checked and ID and .php file name are 100% correct. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constant reload of a DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389562/constant-reload-of-a-div)

Comment: A `<script>` tag can have JavaScript content **or** it can have a "src" attribute. Not both.

Comment: Also note that AJAX polling is a major anti-pattern. Given any decent number of users you will be DDOSing your own server. Use WebSockets instead.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yeah, I suspect so. For now it's just a side project of mine but if ever decide to put that on a server for general use I'll definetly remember your advice to change that to something more efficent and safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to enclose your function within the `<script>` , right now it is started for `<script src="jquery">`

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
(function () {
    $("#comments").load('url to comments.php');
}), 1000);
</script>
</head>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2L854vL3/)**

Comment: setInterval is running even if it's as var. As a proof when I removed script src I was getting errors every second in console. And even if I have it without the var it's still not working.

Comment: Ooooh I see now. I thought that I'm supposed to code in <script> tag with JQ src. Well, now it;s working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you have `setInterval()` call within `<script>` with `src` pointing to jQuery. There are also extra parentheses at `setInterval` function which are not necessary. Use `.ready()` handler to wait until `document` is loaded before calling `setInterval`.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $().ready(function() {
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
                         $("#comments").load('url to comments.php');
                       }, 1000);
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: `$().ready` is deprecated in version 3 http://api.jquery.com/ready/. Preferred is `$(function)`

Comment: @charlietfl Was not sure when jQuery team would eventually deprecate `.ready()`. Does documentation mention the same, yet?

Comment: guessing it will be removed down the road....mentions it is deprecated though. bet it would be a long ways down the road though...would break so many projects since it has been around since day 1

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, read the issue at jQuery github repo some time ago https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3025 _"Realistically speaking, we're not going to be able to remove it in any
non-distant future. For now it's just about stating our intent about some
forms of these APIs being confusing and hence discouraging their use."_ -mgol

Comment: I hardly ever use `ready`, simpler to write `$(func)` ... just checked to see if there was even a warning thrown but didn't get one

Comment: @charlietfl Interestingly, "confusing" is mentioned, though `jQuery()` method itself can perform different operations, depending on parameter passed, as you illustrate `$(func)`. Also, not sure why the decision was made to set `this` to `document` within `.ready()` handler.

Comment: See occasional comments about same methods being both getter/setter or event methods like `click()` being both listener and trigger too. Am so used to it it doesn't confuse me in any way